# Sencha Touch browser-navigation back button

Tags: sencha-touch, back-button

How can I override the functionality of browser's back button? I have navigation view in page and I want to synchronize the browser back button and navigation view's back button. I can override navigation button's functionality but I don't know how to do the same thing for browser back.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use routes, this tutorial will show you how: http://railsdevtricksofthetrade.blogspot.com/2012/04/sencha-touch-2-routes-and-back-button.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

I managed to override the back button of the nav view with the following code

1. In your controller, create a new `ref`:

   ```
   backToNav: 'myNavXtypeName button[text=Back]'
   ```
2. In the same controller, link the ref to a `control`:

   ```
   backToNav: {
           tap: 'backToNav'
   }
   ```
3. Finally create the controller method that implements the navigation view's pop functionality.

   ```
   backToNav: function() {
           Ext.getCmp('myNavXtypeName').pop()
   }
   ```

Done. 
[Read more about refs and controls here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/core_concepts/controllers.html)